# GCloud Firestore Backup --retention flag error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, backup, gcloud

I want to implement a backup for my firestore database. However, when I follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/backups) I come to an annoying error that I can not seem to fix.

I use  the following command:

```
 gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules create --database='(default)' --recurrence=daily --retention=7d
```

I come to the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.firestore.backups.schedules.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid value at 'backup_schedule.retention' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration), Field 'retention', Illegal duration format; duration must end with 's'
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Invalid value at 'backup_schedule.retention' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration),
      Field 'retention', Illegal duration format; duration must end with 's'
    field: backup_schedule.retention
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No I have not yet found a way to solve it sorry.

Comment: Upgrading the terraform solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your gcloud cli to latest version. It worked for me after upgrading to
Google Cloud SDK 450.0.0
alpha 2023.10.06